# Search and format the string

Tags: r, data-transform

Here is my data at below,

[image: Data]

So in my activity description column I have many charges.

Some string contain pattern like charge, charges, or nothing.

So at first,
1. I need to find for **pattern named charge and replace with charges**.

2. But for 2 of the charges named **container charges and store charges I need to name as charge instead of charges. Ex. Container charge not container charges.**
3. If no pattern named charge is present I need to place charges at end of the string.

For Ques 1, I tried below code in R,

```
    df$Activity description = gsub("*charge","charges",df$Activity description)
```

But it replacing additional s in the output as Ex. Chargess. I dont know why.

For ques 2 and 3, I dont know how to start.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I highly recommend you use headers without spaces (ex. Activity_description).

Next, you probably want to use a series of if-else statements:

```
new_column <- c()
for (line in df$Activity_description){
    # check for the two specific cases
    if (line == "Container Tracking Charges"){
        new_column <- c(new_column, "Container Tracking Charge")
    } else if (line == "Store Tracking Charges"){
        new_column <- c(new_column, "Store Tracking Charge")
    } else if (grepl("Charge$", line)){
        new_column <- c(new_column, paste(line,"s",sep=""))
    } else if (! grepl("Charge", line)){
        new_column <- c(new_column, paste(line,"Charges"))
    } else {
        new_column <- c(new_column, line)
    }
}
```

You may then set the original column using the new character vector:

```
df$Activity_description <- new_column
```

This may be a bit simple since it's done in base R, but it should at least get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (there may be an additionnal isue with lowercase and uppercase, so converting anything to lowercase -including patterns in code- may be necessary):

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(Activity_description=c(
   "Fuel Charge",
   "no Charges",
   "Container Charges",
   "Test"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df %>% mutate(Activity_description2=
  Activity_description %>% 
    str_replace("(Charge)\\b","\\1s") %>%
    str_replace("((Container|Store) +Charge)s?","\\1") %>%
    ifelse(str_detect(.,"Charge"),.,paste(.,"Charges"))
)

#  Activity_description Activity_description2
#1          Fuel Charge          Fuel Charges
#2           no Charges            no Charges
#3    Container Charges      Container Charge
#4                 Test          Test Charges
```

Comment: Here im using straightaway , df %>% mutate(df$Activity_description2=
  df$Activity_description %>% 
    str_replace("(Charge)\\b","\\1s") %>%
    str_replace("((Container|Store) +Charge)s?","\\1") %>%
    ifelse(str_detect(.,"Charge"),.,paste(.,"Charges")). After that it is saying error in ")", in str_replace. Some bracket error in third line it seems. Can you help me on this.

Comment: There are 3 closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Things get very easy when you separate into smaller problems. Here I am creating the `test` vector that you can replace in your code by `df$your.column`.

```
test <- c("charge", "charges", "container charges", "store charges", "something else")
```

First you need to define the different conditions like so:

```
haschargeandnotcharges <- grepl("charge", test) & !grepl("charges", test)
hascontainerchargesorstorecharges <- grepl("container charge", test)|grepl("store charge", test)
hasnocharge <- grepl("charge", test)
```

Then you can apply your different rules

```
result <- ifelse(haschargeandnotcharges, gsub("charge", "charges", test), test) 
result <- ifelse(hascontainerchargesorstorecharges, gsub("charges", "charge", result), result) 
result <- ifelse(hascontainerchargesorstorecharges, gsub("charges", "charge", result), result) 
result <- ifelse(hasnocharge, paste(result, "charges"), result) 

rbind(test,result)
       [,1]      [,2]              [,3]                      
test   "charge"  "charges"         "container charges"       
result "charges" "charges charges" "container charge charges"
       [,4]                   [,5]                    
test   "store charges"        "something else"        
result "store charge charges" "something else charges"
```

Next time try to please give us a reproducible example so that we can help you.